# The New York Times App Knows All I Guess

Tags: ios9

As a result of the new News app by Apple in the iOS 9 update, all apps previously in the newsstand folder have been moved to a newsstand folder that is exactly like all of the other folders in iOS. Whenever I open the New York Times app, this is at the top:
[image]

How does the New York Times app know that it is in the newsstand folder? Do all apps have access to their locations?

Comment: If you move the app out of the folder, does the message stop appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming they're simply checking the version and assuming you haven't moved it yet.